# transparency to a single image within the canvas

Tags: javascript

I am trying to give transparency to a single image that I have created on the canvas, globalAlpha does not work for me because I need to only affect one image and that affects all images.

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('cvs');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
var image = new Image();
image.src = "../img/image.jpg";
image.onload = function () {
    ctx.drawImage(image, 200, 200, 100, 100);
}

var image1 = new Image();
image1.src = "../img/image.jpg";
image1.onload = function () {
    ctx.drawImage(image1, 400, 400, 100, 100);
}
```

Comment: Set `globalAlpha` to your transparency level, draw the image, return `globalAlpha` to `1`.

Comment: It worked for me xdd, thanks, mark it as an answer to rate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set `globalAlpha` to your transparency level, draw the image, return `globalAlpha` to 1.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the ctx global alpha around render.

```
image1.onload = function () {
    // Save the original alpha
    ctx.save();
    // Set global alpha
    ctx.globalAlpha = 0.5;
    // Draw
    ctx.drawImage(image1, 400, 400, 100, 100);
    // Restore the original alpha
    ctx.restore();
}
```

Comment: You may want to store the original ctx.globalAlpha and restore it after you're finished drawing. Or maybe not!

Comment: @Brian Hannay You are right, I fixed my code.